# Ionic SQLite inserted value of column TEXT is undefined

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework

I have the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Category(IdCategory INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT, Visible BIT);
```

On databaseService.ts:

```
AddCategory(Name, Visible ) {
    const data = [Name, Visible];
    console.log('adding category: ', data);
    return this.database.executeSql('INSERT INTO Category (`Name`, Visible) VALUES (?, ?)',
    data).then(data2 => {
      this.LoadCategory();
    });
  }
```

the result in the console.log is:

```
adding category:  (2) ["cat 1", true]0: "cat 1"1: truelength: 2__proto__: Array(0)
```

meaning the variables are transmited ok, but then, when I read the rows, I have

```
1, undefined, true
```

Id, Name, Visible.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is welcome! Thanks!

This is the code for the first solution:

INSERT INTO `Category` (Name, Visible) VALUES ("cat2",true)

And I got the same error. The category name is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code

```
AddCategory(Name, Visible ) {
     var sql = "INSERT INTO `Category` (Name,Visible) VALUES ('"+Name+"','"+ Visible+"')";
     this.database.executeSql(sql,{})
     .then(() => this.theConsole += "\n" + 'Executed SQL' + sql)
     .catch(e => this.theConsole += "Error: " + JSON.stringify(e));
 }
```

Comment: I have put the error in the question, to see the code corectly. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at reading the values :) Sorry! The answer helped me to get exceptions. Thanks!